# How to get Named Ranges in PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I want get named ranges in my file. just name of my ranges. in my file, i have ranges 'detail', 'header', 'footer'. this is my function

```
$temp_name = [];
foreach($spreadsheet->getNamedRanges() as $name){
   $temp_name [] = $name;
}
print_r("<br>Temp Name<br>");
print_r($temp_name[]);
print_r("<br><br>");
```

but i get so many value in $temp_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use PhpSpreadsheet, but looking at [their documentation](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/1.6.0/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Spreadsheet.html#method_getNamedRanges), `getNamedRanges` returns an array of `NamedRange`s, which in turn have names, it doesn't return just names alone. So you need to get the name from the range, like -

```
foreach ($spreadsheet->getNamedRanges() as $range) {
    temp_name[] = $range->getName();
}
```

also re: `print_r("<br>Temp Name<br>");` for strings, just use `print '..';`, `print_r()` is for arrays.